# How to handle inventory for product variation?

Tags: mysql, inventory-management

I have seen this question asked for several times on SO but I haven't found the answer that works for me yet.

I'm designing an eCommerce system where we have a simple inventory management system. Basically, each product can have many attributes, and each attribute variation set can have different quantity. The relationship between products and attributes is many2many and is managed elsewhere, the inventory table simply takes care of the "quantity" management only.

So my current approach is to store the combination of attributes values ids as a string in the database (and md5 it and stored in another column for faster searching). This approach allows me to quickly search for the inventory quantity given the list of attributes, and it also allows me to edit easily via admin.

The table has the follow columns (I cut short it a bit to focus on the main structure only)

```
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `container_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `lot_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `facility_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `inventory_item_status_type_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `feature_value_ids` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `key` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `serial` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `quantity_onhand` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

The drawback of this method is

1. If the product have these attributes: 1,2,3,4,5
2. The inventory is defined for 1,3,4 and 1,2,3,4 but not 1,2,3,4,5
3. When the user selects 1,2,3,4,5 then 1 possible desired behavior is that the system should use the quantity of 1,2,3,4 (which is the closest combination it can get). In this case, we may have to use fulltext match for closest combination

For this issue, do you think if there is anything wrong with the above approach, and how would you do it differently?

Answer (score 0):

If you can spare the time to update a table containing: attribute id tuple => list of product_id every time there is an update in the product table, searching for a subset of the attribute can be done quickly with dynamic programming.

I am not sure why you would need to md5 the attribute value ids string in order to search for an exact match. MySQL should be able to index any arbitrary column.

Comment: I see, I just thought that it might be faster to search for a short varchar vs a fulltext. Can you please let me know what you mean by "dynamic programing"?

Comment: A full explanation of dynamic programming is better found via Googling. In short, you cache output for known inputs, then solve your problem by recursively solving the same problem at a smaller size.